# how to copy file from one location to another location dynamically using java

Tags: java, file

We are trying to copy a file from one location to another location. We succeed To move files from one location to another location. But, I want to copy only particular file to another location dynamically.

```
import java.io.File;

public class fileTranfer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           File sourceFolder = new File("C:/offcial/BPM/Veriflow");
           File destinationFolder = new File("C:/offcial/BPM/Veriflow2");

           if (!destinationFolder.exists())
           {
               destinationFolder.mkdirs();
           }

           // Check weather source exists and it is folder.
           if (sourceFolder.exists() && sourceFolder.isDirectory())
           {
               // Get list of the files and iterate over them
               File[] listOfFiles = sourceFolder.listFiles();

               if (listOfFiles != null)
               {
                   for (File child : listOfFiles )
                   {
                       // Move files to destination folder
                       child.renameTo(new File(destinationFolder + "\\" + child.getName()));
                   }

               }
               System.out.println(destinationFolder + "  files transfered.");
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println(sourceFolder + "  Folder does not exists");
           }

    }

}
```

If any one have the sample please provide me...

Comment: Read about FilenameFilter. But your question is very unclear

Answer (score 1):

I would create a byte[] buffer, read the first files contents into the buffer. then create the second file new File() give it the path you want, and throw in the buffered data into the new file.

```
private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT : Homework should go into the size of the byte array called buffer. 1024 is standard, but you may tweak the value!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

It has quite some nice utility-methods for checking equality and copying files and directories in [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

If the whole lib should be overkill just take a look into the [FileUtils-Class via grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java/) :)

Comment: Wouldn't downloading a libary just for copying a file a bit too overkill?

Comment: Probably depends on how much file handling stuff they want to do. When he decides it to be overkill he could just take a look into the [FileUtils-Class  via grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java/) :)